# importing a package in ros2 pubsub

Tags: python-packaging, ros2

I am modifying the ros2 pubsub tutorial https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html

The directory structure looks like:

```
   src 
│   ├── build/
|   ├── install/
|   ├── logs/
│   ├── py_pubsub
│   │   ├── py_pubsub
│   │   |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   |   ├── publisher_member_function.py
│   │   |   ├── subscriber_member_function.py
│   │   ├── resources/
|   |   └──results/
│   ├── package.xml
|   ├── setup.cfg   
|   └── setup.py   
|
└──my_package/
```

inside subscriber_member_function.py I have

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../')
import my_package
```

If I run `python3 subscriber_member_function.py` then all of the imports and related code work.

However if run

```
/src$ colcon build --packages-select py_pubsub
/src$ . install/setup.bash
/src$ ros2 run py_pubsub listener
```

then I get a ModuleNotFoundError

If I remove the import of my_package, then running the listener with ros2 also works.

Comment: What is my_package? Where is it located? Has it been added as a dependency to your existing package py_pubsub?

Comment: Specifically it is this folder 'spotmicro' https://github.com/OpenQuadruped/spot_mini_mini/tree/spot/spotmicro, and is located at the same level as 'src'. Or more accurately I put a src folder within spot_mini_mini. I haven't added it as a dependency, could you say more about that?

Comment: @pongoS have you found a solution for your problem? I'm facing the same issue at the moment :)

Comment: not exactly. I did find that packages need to be added to the setup.py so that it can find them, but I never got that working and ended up completely restarting my project in a different way to where this question isn't relevant anymore.